# What is the fastest way to create cube 1000^3 in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I need to create 3-dimensional array in MongoDB (2.6.7) to store, at least, x-y-z coordinates and value. What is the most efficient way to do it: what structure should be and how to create it fast?
I tried to use next script, but it worked to long:

```
function insertMatrix3(dbName, colName, numX, numY, numZ) {
    var col = db.getSiblingDB(dbName).getCollection(colName);
    var array = [];
    for (x = 0; x < numX; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < numY; y++) {
            for (z = 0; z < numZ; z++) {
                array.push(
                {
                    x : x,
                    y : y,
                    z : z,
                    val : 0
                }
                );
            }
        }
        if (x % 5 == 0) {
            col.insert(array);
            array = [];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How long exactly did your script work? And what is the maximum time you are okay with?

Comment: Actually I didn't wait until completion because it took about 20 hours and I just stopped it (before it I checked the size of already created database - it was 153 GB). I would be nice to spend less than 1 hour on it, but the write operation (creation of database) has low priority, the read is important. My machine has i5-4670, 16 GB RAM and ordinary HDD.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Knowing what the context is for creating this giant lattice would help us recommend the best option.

Answer (score 0):

With using of bulk operations (here is manual:
 [Bulk Write Operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/)), it took 261 minutes to create such array (1000*1000*1000).

```
function insertMatrix3Bulk(dbName, colName, numX, numY, numZ) {
    var localDB = db.getSiblingDB(dbName);
    var col = localDB.getCollection(colName);
    for (x = 0; x < numX; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < numY; y++) {
            var bulk = col.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
            for (z = 0; z < numZ; z++) {
                bulk.insert(
                    {
                        x : x,
                        y : y,
                        z : z,
                        val : 0
                    }
                );
            }
            bulk.execute();
        }
    }
}
```